# graceful-fs warning messages each time when type npm

Tags: node.js, npm

Just installed Node 6.9.1

`npm` - 3.10.8

When I type `npm -v` I am receiving the following warning  `re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.`

How to get rid off this message?

I've tried `npm uninstall graceful-fs -g`, 
 `npm install -g graceful-fs graceful-fs@latest`.

Then type `npm list graceful-js -g` shows:

`` +-- ember-cli@2.6.0
| +-- bower-config@1.4.0
| | `-- graceful-fs@4.1.11
| `-- npm@2.15.1
|   `-- graceful-fs@4.1.11
`-- graceful-fs@4.1.11 ``

npm@2.15.1 was using 4.1.3 - I think this version doesn't exits. [graceful-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graceful-fs). but I have fix it manually.

Before that I've tried [this commands](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v2.6.0)

And still when type `npm -v`, cmd shows me a around 5-6 warnings ...

**Edit**

tree dependency  `npm list graceful-js -g`
The difference is that I just installed `grunt` globally

`` +-- ember-cli@2.10.0
| +-- bower-config@1.4.0
| | `-- graceful-fs@4.1.11
| `-- npm@3.10.8
|   `-- graceful-fs@4.1.6
+-- graceful-fs@4.1.11
`-- grunt@1.0.1
  `-- dateformat@1.0.12
    `-- meow@3.7.0
      `-- read-pkg-up@1.0.1
        `-- read-pkg@1.1.0
          `-- load-json-file@1.1.0
            `-- graceful-fs@4.1.11 ``

**Edit 2**

After `npm la ember-cli -g` The output is :

`Command line tool for developing ambitious ember.js apps` 
`git+https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli.git` 
`https://ember-cli.com/`

Comment: Try `npm uninstall ember-cli -g`, `npm install ember-cli -g`. I think later versions use newer dependencies, which should mitigate the issue.

Comment: Still the same result

Comment: Could you check which version of `ember-cli` is installed now?

Comment: `npm list ember-cli -g` shows me `-- ember-cli@2.10.0`

Comment: Very odd, I would have expected that to resolve the issue. Could you paste in the full dependency tree again in your question?

Comment: Yes check the updated question. Maybe I should say that I have installed node js version with packages, but I have deleted it and installed new version of node js,

Comment: Could `iojs` couse this problems ?

Comment: Potentially - I would uninstall it if you don't need it.

Comment: iojs is removed, but it's still the same. I don't know what else to check ...

Comment: You could try `npm la ember-cli -g` which will give you the verbose output which might be helpful. Paste that into the question in case there's a really outdated version somewhere.

Comment: @Aurora0001  check the updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 15 hours of digging, I found the solution:

- Download the latest stable version of [graceful-fs](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs) that pass the [tests](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs/commits/master) on your desktop.
- Go to `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules`
- find which of the packages are using `graceful-fs`. Navigate to their `node_modules` folders and replace manually with downloaded files from GitHub.
- Do this for all packages.

In my case I used version 3.0.8.

Hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

My current progress:

Just made a C# console application to read all files in the Windows that contains 'graceful-fs'. The first result was very interesting: 
`C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\375.70\Win10_64\International\nodejs\NVIDIA Web Helper.exe` that contains Javascript code, and the following code block:

```js
if (e.code !== 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') {throw e};

// TODO(ChALkeR): remove this in master after 6.x
// This code was based upon internal/util and is required to give users
// a grace period before actually breaking modules that re-evaluate fs
// sources from context where internal modules are not allowed, e.g.
// older versions of graceful-fs module.

const prefix = `(${process.release.name}:${process.pid}) `;

printDeprecation = function(msg, warned) {
if (process.noDeprecation)
  return true;

if (warned)
  return warned;

if (process.throwDeprecation)
  throw new Error(`${prefix}${msg}`);
else if (process.traceDeprecation)
  console.trace(msg);
else
  console.error(`${prefix}${msg}`);

return true;
};
printDeprecation('fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not ' +
               'supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, ' +
               'please update it to a more recent version.',
                false);
```

I've updated NVidia Drivers, but currently I searching where they are installed. I start wondering the warning is caused by drivers.