# Cannot fix npm "fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported..."

Tags: npm

Any call to npm results in a list of messages going:

> fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.

I've checked the threads here and elsewhere but there's nothing I can do to fix it.
Even `npm install nvm` throws the same message

---

it all started with the below:

> npm install -g nativescript
>
> Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, mkdir '/usr/local/include/(node:10542) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
> (node:10542) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
> (node:10542) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
> /usr/local'

Trying to upgrade graceful-fs throws the same error bu the way

Comment: [graceful-fs warning messages each time when type npm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40948676/graceful-fs-warning-messages-each-time-when-type-npm) seems related.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by downgrading node.

1. Had to install nvm here https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.markdown#install-script
2. and then run nvm install 5.12.0

The error is gone. What a story (and what a waste of time)